# I want to create a Weibull probability Plot in Angular

Tags: python-3.x, angular, d3.js, highcharts, weibull

This is the chart i am trying to create in Angular. This comes from the reliability package in python.

[image]

https://github.com/MatthewReid854/reliability/tree/master/reliability
I am using Highchart - Area-Range + scatter. I am able to fix the x-axis as it is just logarithmic scale. But I am unable to fix the y -axis

For Weibull analysis, formula for Y-Axis Scale is as:   ln(-ln(1-p))

where p=(i-0.3)/(n+0.4) and i is the rank of the observation. This scale is chosen in order to linearize the resulting plot for Weibull data.

```
weibullHighcharts(weibullresp:any,statDataresp:any){
  
    const chart = Highcharts.chart('chart-gauge', {
     
      chart: {
        marginTop: 5,
        height: 380,
        inverted: true,
        zoomType: 'xy',
        credits: false,
        events: {
          
          load() {
           
            
            let chart = this;
          
            
          },
        },
    },
      title: {
        credits: false,
        text: '',
      },
      xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        labels: {
            format: '{value}%'
          },
            type: 'logarithmic',
            reversed: false,
            min: 0.1,
            max:90,
            title: {
                enabled: true,
                text: 'Fraction Failure'
            },
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            showLastLabel: true
        }, 

        
        yAxis: {
          gridLineWidth: 1,
          max: 999,
          min: 10,
          type: 'logarithmic',
         
          title: {
              text: 'Days to Failure'
          }
      },
      legend: {
        credits: false,
          layout: 'vertical',
          align: 'left',
          verticalAlign: 'top',
          floating: true,
          borderWidth: 1
      },
      series: [
          {
            color:'#0000FF',
          showInLegend:false,
          type: 'line',
          data: weibullresp.averages,
          zIndex: 1,  
          marker: {
              lineWidth: 2,
          }},
           {
          showInLegend:false,
          data: weibullresp.ranges,
          type: 'arearange',
          lineWidth: 0,
          linkedTo: ':previous',
          fillOpacity: 0.3,
          zIndex: 0,
          marker: {
              enabled: false
          }},
          {
              showInLegend:false,
              type:'scatter',
              data: weibullresp.scatterData,
              color:'#343434',
              marker: {
                radius: 2,
                
                symbol: 'circle'
              }
          }
  ],
    
      credits: {
        enabled: false, 
      },
    
    } as any);

   
  }
```

Is there a package for python where Weibull plot can be created?
How to fix the y-axis in Highchart?

[image]

Kindly help me fix the y-axis in Highchart or Let me know how can i achieve the the python image shared in front end -Angular. I need exactly same image in Python

Comment: Here is link how to configure Highcharts with Python, [python-angular-and-highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/python-angular-and-highcharts)

Comment: In Highchart, For axis-type , we have log but we don't have Weibull axis as shown in the Python graph for Y-axis. The requirement is to change the y-axis as per the Weibull probability plot

Comment: What exactly do you want to change in yAxis? Could you prepare an example with your sample data in the online code editor?

Comment: I want to change the y-axis exactly as in the first graph i shared(created in python).In that graph you can see the x-axis is logarithmic while the y-axis neither log or linear. I want to create exactly same axis as in python graph.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change [tickInterval](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickInterval), [minorTickInterval](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.minorTickInterval) on axis.

> On logarithmic axes, the unit is the power of the value. For example, setting the minorTickInterval to 1 puts one tick on each of 0.1, 1, 10, 100 etc. Setting the minorTickInterval to 0.1 produces 9 ticks between 1 and 10, 10 and 100 etc.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Logarithmic axis demo'
  },
  xAxis: {
    tickInterval: 1,
    type: 'logarithmic',
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'logarithmic',
    minorTickInterval: 0.1,
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br />',
    pointFormat: 'x = {point.x}, y = {point.y}'
  },
  series: [{
    data: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512],
    pointStart: 1
  }]
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x21uc5sd/